# how do i improve my HDMI resolution

Tags: hdmi

my video resolution has always been great!
but i downloaded a graphical interface for my pi Bluetooth and know i can not achieve a good picture on my hdmi to my tv
the code was downloaded from 
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez blueman

Answer (score 0):

OK i found that CEA mode 34 is the correct selection in the Raspberry PI config to display on my HDMI input to mt Sony TV.
and the downloaded code for the Bluetooth graphical interface was not the cause to my display problems and it seems to be just a coincidence that it happened at the same time.